# How to show content of one monitor inside window on extended desktop?

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors, extended-desktop

I have connected 3 monitors to my computer. Third one is big TV I can't see while at keyboard.

But I would like to run some video and presentations on it, controlling them at keyboard.

How to do that?

It would be great if I could see what people see on big TV in a small window on my main monitor.

Is it possible?

I would like config be at extended desktop mode.

Answer (score 2):

#### This is possible by remote viewer connected to computer itself.

I used [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/) – see the result:

[image]

You should be able to achieve this also with other similar products.

Steps:

1. Download and install TightVNC client + server from their [download page](http://www.tightvnc.com/download.php).
2. In server setup window, allow loopback connections:
   [image]
3. Launch the client and enter `localhost` as remote host address.

**Note:** Maybe TightVNC server always transmits only *top left corner* of the virtual rectangle which includes all your displays. So make sure that your TV view is in the top left corner of that rectangle (i.e. it is topmost and leftmost monitor in **Display** control panel.)